# Angular2 Route with childs in RC6

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I m new in Angular2 and I m trying to add some routes into my app. I have two separated routing files:

app.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**', component: My404Component
  }
];


export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and dashboard.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        component: ChildComponent,
      },

    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  }
];


export const dashboardRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes);
```

If I access to http://localhost:3000/dashboard I receive and 404 page error, but if I access to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/child I can see the page.

If I delete the `children` property inside dashboard, i can access to http://localhost:3000/dashboard and see the page...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full',  component: LoginComponent }, // order matters
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', component: My404Component }
];
```

Add a default route to the child routes as well:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'child', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent, },
  ],
  }
];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer :) . With your changes now the 404 page isn't appear, but automatically redirects me to /dashboard/child when I try to access to /dashboard. Is there a way to access to /dashboard and see the "dashboard's template"?

Comment: If `DashboardComponent` has a `<router-outlet>` than *a* child route needs to be provided. You can add a `Dummy` component that shows nothing to the `path: ''` child route instead of `redirectTo`.